# Windows server 2012 r2 x64 turn black screen after login

Tags: hyper-v, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I'm new to windows server anyway especially windows 2012s, actually server was there for only Ncomputing devices,so i messed-up with it by installing **AD** and 
**Hyper- V**, after seeing those feature affect my Ncomputing environment i just remove them, it took a time to restart anyway and after finish restarting i cant get in to my Local account and i successfully get in to Domain again with black screen and cursor only that, i trried to find ways through google but nothing exactly, somebody with an idea out-there help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it work fine for me, i just [repair master boot record](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows) and it work perfect to me